# How do I get the maximum resolution supported by my webcam in Java?

Tags: java, media, webcam, resolution

Using any non-deprecated open source Java Multimedia/Webcam API (or any Java or even C++ code linked to Java code), I need to get the image size that is actually received from a webcam device and the maximum real image resolution that a webcam device offers. So if I plug in a 720 by 1280 pixel webcam device into the USB slot of my desktop, I want the code to give me (720,1280). If I unplug that USB webcam and then plug in a different, 640 by 480 video resolution webcam, I want the code to give me (640,480).

How do I get the maximum resolution supported by my webcam in Java (or C++ linked to Java)?

I don't care what library or code you use, I just need a way to get the resolution.

Comment: Please edit additions into your question, don't post them as comments. However by the looks of it, you are looking for library suggestions, those are off topic.

Comment: I don't care what library or code you use, I just need a way to get the resolution.

Comment: [without opening up the owners manual of the webcam I am using]

Answer (score 0):

Create a BufferedImage and then get the dimensions of that image.